# A route named 'Admin_default' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Parameter name: name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

I have an ECommerece site which had some issues regarding Nuget Updates. I did all kind of updates but now I am facing another Issues at RunTime which i never faced before.

**A route named 'Admin_default' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name**

I checked my Entire solution, there is no any other Route name 'Admin_default'.
It has only one Route.  I tried to Rename the Route and Run, It Run successfully for the first time.
but when i Stop it. Rebuild the Solution and then Run again. then It Again give me the same issue with new Name of Route.

Also I checked all of other posts related to my issue. but can't fix my bug.

**Edit:**
I did all kind of Deletion of folder bin and Obj. It works only for the first time when I Run. for the 2nd time I get same issue again with new name of Route.

The main issue is that. I need to Clean my Solution each time before Run.
If I do not Clean it before Run, it will give me this issue.

But I want It should automatically be Replaced with old dll file on Build command. and do not need to Clean Manually.
But It need to Delete ( Clean ) the previous dll manually before Rebuild.

Can I have any technique through which i don't need to clean solution manually and I Rebuild solution successfully and Replace old dll automatically.?

Comment: Go to the bin folder on your project, delete all DLL files and then rebuild. This is worth trying

Comment: Did you create some plugins? maybe uninstall those plugins if you have and see if the problem is persisting after.

Comment: No, I do not installed any plugin fresh. All of plugins are old when the solution was OK.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a similar problem has been logged [on the nopcommerce site](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/21925/a-route-named-homepage-is-already-in-the-route-collection-route-names-must-be-unique.aspx).

Read it and let us know if the described solution(s) worked for you.